# HereMaps API endpoint returns json with newline characters

Tags: here-api

I'm having trouble with Here-maps.

Core API call to this endpoint:

`https://1.traffic.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/info?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=<app-id>&app_code=<app-code>&output=json`

returns JSON which contains tabs and new-line characters which cause an error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

I don't really think there is a way to fix this on my side. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, would you please share your source code causing the error?

Comment: I can try to extract code, but I don't think the problem is on my side. If you try to call the endpoint the response is not valid JSON.

Comment: The bug is even present in the demo code provided on your documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you,

Response structure was fixed by @HEREDeveloperSupport.